# Gradle Sync Fail

Tags: android, gradle

I get this error when trying to build my app:

```
Could not find com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1
Required by:
MyApp:app:unspecified
```

Gradle version:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-alpha2'
```

Android studio version;

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "MyApp"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

I tried going to SDK TOOLS and enabling the constraint solver, but I did not help. This happened just today, and have not have had this issue earlier. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the version of your android studio?

Comment: @shuvro I added it to my post

Comment: no, I didn't ask about sdk version, I asked about android studio version . Like.

Comment: @shuvro oh sorry, then it's 2.2 RC 2.

Comment: I think you have AS 2.3 because you are using com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-alpha2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have installed ConstraintLayout. Open SDK Manager and than in SDK Tools tab you can check what version of ConstarintLayout is installed.

[image: SDK Tools]

Comment: Mine says 40.0.0 and 39 (Google Repository), what do I do now?

Comment: But do you have ConstraintLayout installed?

Comment: Yes, I have checked both boxes in SDK Tools.

Comment: Oh, I clicked "show package Details" and could see that the alpha1 options is gone, and I have alpha8 and beta4. Which version should I use? I can now build my project if I change in gradle to alpha8.

Comment: You should use the most recent version. In this case it will be beta4.